i have a code from tutorial that allowed me to access files and there is ".%2e" line, what is ".%2e" code mean?
Hey i'm new to the cybersecurity and i'm doing pentesting tutorial there is a command to access hidden folder which is written
curl localhost:80/cgi-bin/.%2e/.%2e/.%2e/.%2e/TargetDirectoryPath
what is .%2e meaning and what did it do?
i want to know the way it works

"Period, dot or full stop".
Here is a table of ascii codes: https://www.ascii-code.com/
/../../ is a special path, and systems disagree about how to interpret it, or if it should be blocked.  By coding one dot explicitly ".", and the other dot as a character encoding "%2e", the author hopes to get past interpretation problems and security blocks.
